ZynqMP memset() raises unhandled alignment fault error
I'm having trouble using memset() in C; let me explain.
I'm working with embedded Linux on a zynq ultrascale+ board running Linux kernel v4.14. I'm performing some DMA transfers from the logic side of the FPGA to the processing system (PS), so I set aside a RAM section so the kernel doesn't use it...
I added this to the devicetree.
memory@0 {

    device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7ff00000>, <0x00000008 0x00000000 0x0 0x80000000>;
    };

    reserved-memory {
        compatible = "xlnx,reserved-memory";
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        ranges;

        reserved: buffer@800000000 {
            no-map;
            reg = <0x00000008 0x00000000 0x0 0x40000000>;
        };
    };

It reserves the memory as specified.
When I wrote my.c code to use this reserved memory, it worked properly except for the use of the memset() function...
If I try to use memset(ram_vaddress, 0, size);, I get this:
[ 2386.395781] test[3691]: unhandled alignment fault (7) at 0x7f9cb88080, esr 0x92000061, in libc-2.27.so[7f9c926000+13b000]
...
Bus error (core dumped)

If I use a for loop to iterate through all memory addresses and set it to 0, it works, but it is extremely slow.
I'm not very experienced with memory management, etc. So maybe I'm missing a concept or doing something incorrectly.
It appears that the allocated virtual memory is not continuous or aligned, but I am unable to determine why. Debugging the physical address, I can read what I write on it, indicating that the part that connects to the physical address works.
Here is the code below.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "parameters.h"

// Allocate memory
int configure_memory_allocation(size_t size, unsigned int **virtual_addr, uint64_t physical_address)\
{    
    // Open /dev/mem which represents the whole physical memory
    int memory_handle = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

    if (memory_handle < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    *virtual_addr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memory_handle, physical_address); // Memory map source address

    if (*virtual_addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        close(memory_handle);
        return 1;
    }

    close(memory_handle);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{    
    // Variables
    size_t size = 4096;
    uint64_t physical_address = 0x800000000;

    // Mapped devices
    unsigned int *ram_vaddress = NULL;

    if (configure_memory_allocation(size, &ram_vaddress, physical_address) != 0) {
        // Handle error
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to configure memory allocation.\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("configure_memory_allocation successfully\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 4; i++) {
        ram_vaddress[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%08x ram_vaddress[%d] = %d\n", &ram_vaddress[i], i, ram_vaddress[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    // Use memset to clear the memory
    memset(ram_vaddress, 0, size);

    munmap(ram_vaddress, size);
}

I tried memset(&ram_vaddress, 0, size); and memset(&ram_vaddress[0], 0, size); in a desperate attempt to work around.

"It reserves the memory as specified" -- And your specification (that you copied from ???) includes the no-map property, which you are violating when you try to access this "reserved" memory region from userspace. The Device Tree documentation describes the no-map property as "indicates the operating system must not ...  permit speculative access to it under`any circumstances other than under the control of the device driver using the region."

Hi,
I copied it from this link. It's not specified. I just didn't want the kernel to use this space; should I create a driver to properly handle this memory region?

What happens if you remove the no-map property from that node, and then run your program?
